# Заполнение текстового поля React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap

Есть вот такая форма:

```
class App extends Component{
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
      email: '',
      message:''  
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
  }
  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value})
  }
  render(){
  return (
   <Form style={{width: '600px'}}>
     <FormGroup>
       <Label for="email">Email:</Label>
       <Input
          type="email"
          name="email"
          onChange={this.handleChange}/>
     </FormGroup>

     <FormGroup>
       <Label for="message">Message:</Label>
       <Input
          type="textarea"
          name="message"
          onChange={this.handleChange}/>
     </FormGroup>
     <Button>Submit</Button>
   </Form>
  );
}
}

export default App;
```

И вот такой скрипт:

```
let obj1 = {
  "URL1": "Something1",
  "URL2": "Something2",
  "URL3": "Something3"
};
let obj2 = {
  "URL1" : "Something11",
  "ULR3" : "Something",
  "ULR2": "Something4"
}

function checkHash(hash1, hash2) {
  let res = {
    changed: [],
    added: [],
    deleted: []
  };
  const hash1Keys = Object.keys(hash1).sort();
  const hash2Keys = Object.keys(hash2).sort();

  if (hash1Keys.join('') !== hash2Keys.join('')) {
    res = {
      ...res,
      deleted: [
        ...res.deleted,
        hash1Keys.find(item => !hash2Keys.includes(item))
      ]
    }
  }

  return hash2Keys.reduce((acc, key) => {
    return !(key in hash1) ? { ...acc,
        added: [...acc.added, key]
      } :
      (hash2[key] !== hash1[key]) ? { ...acc,
        changed: [...acc.changed, key]
      } : acc;
  }, res);
}

const result = checkHash(obj1, obj2);

console.log(`Изменено: ${result.changed.join(', ')}; Удалено: ${result.deleted.join(', ')}; Добавлено: ${result.added.join(', ')}`)
```

Как можно реализовать заполнение текстового поля результатом скрипта?

Answer (score 0):

checkHash выдаёт объект:

```
  {"changed":["URL1"],"added":["ULR2","ULR3"],"deleted":["URL2"]}
```

как именно необходимо заполнить поля?
просто заполнить текстовое поле?

```
const result = JSON.stringify(checkHash(obj1, obj2));
<input type="textarea" value={result} />
```